# Flutter - Width of a chip and IconButton

Tags: flutter

I got a `BottomAppBar` and I want to align the items inside it the following way:
The first 2 items `(IconButtons)` should be placed at the beginning of the row, the third (a Chip wrapped in a `GestureDetector`) in the middle of the screen and the last one `(Logo -> Image)` at the end of the row.
I tried to solve it by calculating the left padding but unfortunately, I don't know how to access the width of `IconButtons` and `Chips`.

Is there a way similar like `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` or `appBar.preferredSize.height` for these items? Working with Spacers or a CrossAxisAlignment doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you try using `Spacer` with `flex` value?

Comment: I tried it now but this isn't working as well